# close(fd) may be async function? how to trigger it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel

What conditions can call `schedule_delayed_work`?

According to the code [linux_kernel_close_code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/fs/file_table.c#L263)(close->sys_close->filp_close->fput), It needs `in_interrupt()` return `TRUE`. But how to make `in_interrupt()` return `TRUE`? What should I do?

the code:

```
void fput(struct file *file)
{
    if (atomic_long_dec_and_test(&file->f_count)) {
        struct task_struct *task = current;

        if (likely(!in_interrupt() && !(task->flags & PF_KTHREAD))) {
            init_task_work(&file->f_u.fu_rcuhead, ____fput);
            if (!task_work_add(task, &file->f_u.fu_rcuhead, true))
                return;
            /*
             * After this task has run exit_task_work(),
             * task_work_add() will fail.  Fall through to delayed
             * fput to avoid leaking *file.
             */
        }

        if (llist_add(&file->f_u.fu_llist, &delayed_fput_list))
            schedule_delayed_work(&delayed_fput_work, 1);
    }
}
```

what condition can trigger `schedule_delayed_work`? I want to recur it by myself.

Comment: In Linux kernel code, it uses `in_interrupt()` to check whether the process is in INTERRUPT or not. 
How to make the process be in INTERRUPT. what about sending some SIGNAL to the process?

Comment: If you search for `in_interrupt` on the same site, you'll see it is related to IRQ and NMI. These are both types of hardware interrupt handled by drivers, not process-level signal handlers.

Comment: And it's a good practice to quickly acknowledge interrupts, to avoid stalling the entire computer. So if I/O is necessary in response to an interrupt, you  schedule the I/O instead of doing it immediately.

Comment: All answers look like the `close(fd)` may be an async function because the `schedule_delayed_work` will add the task to a queue. AND the `schedule_delayed_work` cannot be triggered easily.